# WCF: The socket connection was aborted in-spite of having large timeout values

Tags: c#, wcf

in-spite  of  configuring large timeout values, i am still getting "The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '10:10:10'."

My Client web.config looks like this:

```
<bindings>
      <customBinding>      
        <binding name="HttpBinding" openTimeout="1:00:00" sendTimeout="1:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" closeTimeout="1:00:00">
          <binaryMessageEncoding>
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="4194304" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4194304" maxNameTableCharCount="4194304" />
          </binaryMessageEncoding>
          <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
        </binding>    
   <binding name="CustomNetTcpBindingConfig" openTimeout="1:00:00" sendTimeout="1:00:00" receiveTimeout="1:00:00" closeTimeout="1:00:00" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"  maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4194304" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" >
        <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip">    
<readerQuotas maxDepth="4194304" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4194304" maxNameTableCharCount="4194304" />       
         </binaryMessageEncoding>
             <windowsStreamSecurity protectionLevel="None" />     
        <tcpTransport /> 
    </binding>
      </customBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IDataUploader" closeTimeout="10:01:00" openTimeout="11:01:00" receiveTimeout="11:10:00" sendTimeout="11:01:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Streamed" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="10000000" maxBufferSize="100000000" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="100000000">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="4194304" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4194304" maxNameTableCharCount="4194304" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="10:10:00" enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>

<endpoint address="net.tcp://corp.address.com/FileTransferService" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomNetTcpBindingConfig" contract="Intel.ATRMS.IDataUploader" name="NetTcpBinding_IDataUploader">
        <identity>
          <servicePrincipalName value="" />
          <dns value="corp.address.com" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>

 <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ClientBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MTServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="75" maxConcurrentSessions="75" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

My Server side config looks like this :

```
 <configuration>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
          <service behaviorConfiguration="StreamsBehaviour"
            name="data.StreamedFileTransfer.StreamHandler">

            <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomNetTcpBindingConfig"
              contract="data.StreamedFileTransfer.IDataUploader" name="NetTcpBinding_IDataUploader">
          <identity>
            <dns value="corp.address.com" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />

        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://corp.address.com/FileTransferService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="StreamsBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding
        openTimeout="01:00:00"
        closeTimeout="01:00:00"
        receiveTimeout="01:00:00"
        sendTimeout="01:00:00"
        transferMode="Streamed"
        maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
        maxBufferSize="2147483647"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
        name="MainBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>

        </binding>

      </netTcpBinding>
<customBinding>
<binding name="CustomNetTcpBindingConfig" closeTimeout="1:00:00" openTimeout="1:00:00" receiveTimeout="1:00:00" sendTimeout="1:00:00"       maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
        maxBufferSize="2147483647"    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
     <windowsStreamSecurity  protectionLevel="None" />    
 <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip">
<readerQuotas maxDepth="4194304" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4194304" maxNameTableCharCount="4194304" />       
</binaryMessageEncoding>
 <tcpTransport /> 
    </binding>
</customBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Went through most of the solutions on stackoverflow. But still i am getting same error.

some forums sites which i referred

1. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ed0fd370-fa14-4c40-8068-4327786f1f49/the-socket-connection-was-aborted-this-could-be-caused-by-an-error-processing-your-message-or-a?forum=wcf
2. https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/633699/Socket-Exception-WCF

Edit:

1. It is failing for only large files like 100 MB. But i am able to upload 10 KB files.
2. Set all the attributes values such as (MaxItemsInObjectGraph, MaxReceivedMessageSize, MaxBufferPoolSize, MaxBufferSize, MaxArrayLength) to maximum.

Please guide me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The socket connection was aborted - CommunicationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441844/the-socket-connection-was-aborted-communicationexception)

Comment: Nope. It is failing  for Only large files